# Cassandra configuration of compaction parameters

Tags: cassandra

I am reading cassandra yml to tune some parameters to optimize the performance.

```
# Throttles compaction to the given total throughput across the entire
# system. The faster you insert data, the faster you need to compact in
# order to keep the sstable count down, but in general, setting this to
# 16 to 32 times the rate you are inserting data is more than sufficient.
# Setting this to 0 disables throttling. Note that this account for all types
# of compaction, including validation compaction.
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
```

Here cassandra have recommended to keep "compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec" 16 to 32 times of rate of data insert.We are inserting data with bulk loader which insert data at very high rate. Should I change this setting? OR it should be kept as it is ?

Comment: IN addition to specifying a value in the configuration file, you can use `nodetool` to change the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So do you have an idea on how much data your bulk loader will push in per second? Is that a sustained load or is it bursty? If you do know that, then you basically just follow the guideline in the config files comment for that parameter.

I suspect that you don't have that information, in which case the question is whether your system is misbehaving or not (do you currently see issues?). Sorry I don't know of a good way to otherwise predict that, this is a tuning exercise. You want to find a value that guarantees that Cassandra is not falling behind on compaction, but at the same time you don't want compaction to kill you disk i/o. The only way to figure that out (that I know off) is to try and observe.